# Bitnami - Multiple sites on one stack

Tags: php, .htaccess, silverstripe, bitnami

I am wanting to run a few sites using one Bitnami VM on VirtualBox - I am using the Silverstripe stack. 
Is it possible to set it up so that I can run many sites in different folders?

So `192.168.1.80/site1` and `192.168.1.80/site2` will contain totally different sites.

Currently going to `192.168.1.80/site1` tries to redirect me to 192.168.1.80/install.php, however `192.168.1.80/site1/index.html` will display.

Does it need an .htaccess tweak?

Answer (score 2):

Bitnami Engineer here,

SilverStripe has its own plugin to manage different subsites from a single SilverStripe application. That plugin is called "Subsites" and you will need to install it in the application.

After that, you could create different subsites for different campaigns. You will probably find more information in this link:

https://userhelp.silverstripe.org/en/3.6/optional_features/working_with_multiple_sites/

In case you want to have different SilverStripe applications, you will need to create databases for each of them and deploy them manually. Please note that you will also need to modify the Apache configuration files that you will find at installdir/apache2/conf/

https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/infrastructure/lamp/#how-to-create-a-custom-php-application

Regards,
Jota

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description it sounds like you want to run multiple installations of SilverStripe. If this is the case, you might have to update your RewriteBase in .htaccess e.g

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /site1
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of SilverStripe is Bitnami using at this current time? You'll need to be careful as there are differences in 3.* and 4.*.

https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-subsites

But it does sounds like Subsites is your best answer for a single installation, otherwise you'll be installing a new installation of SS for each site. which will get very tedious.